# Power Automate sync/download to Dropbox file at URL link in email

Tags: email, automation, html-parsing, dropbox, power-automate

I am trying to create a Power Automate flow that automatically syncs to Dropbox a file contained at a URL link in emails.

The email is always from the same email address, let's say: "example@example.com"

The URL link always has the same hyperlinked text: "Link to Signed Affidavit with Original Document Attached"

The URL link itself is dynamic and looks something like this (example): http://www.example.net/asp/showattachment.aspx?BlobID=aso23-gjin42-skgn34-23632

Each such email only contains one such link.

When the link is clicked, it goes to a PDF file in the webrowser. The link is not redirected to a different link.

I'd like this to trigger every time such an email is received. I'd like this to operate in the cloud without any desktop interaction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself.

In the "Compose" section, you need to parse out the URL from the email body using your own code. Below is what I used for my specific usage case. For my specific situation, I knew the URL would always be the same number of characters. If the URL length varies between emails, you'll need a more complex parse.

substring(outputs('Html_to_text')?['body'],add(58,indexof(outputs('Html_to_text')?['body'],'Link to Signed Affidavit')),95)

[image]

[image]